# Chrome extension: can't get message passing to work between background script and content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm essentially trying to get persistent storage for my chrome extension by using the `localStorage` object from a background script.

Here's the setup:

I have one background script and one content script. The content script needs to get / set data from the extension's `localStorage`.

However, i'm stuck getting messages to send to the background script.

Here's the code in the background script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log(sender.tab ? "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url : "from the extension");
  if (request.greeting == "hello")
    sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
});
```

And the content script:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
  });
}, 5000);
```

Ideally the background script should output `from a content script: [some url]` and the content script should output `goodbye`. Instead i get the following error:

```
Port: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

Any help / suggestions are appreciated!

Thanks :)

**Edit: Manifest**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Helios",
  "description": "Helios chrome extension.",
  "version": "0.0.1",

  "permissions": [
    "https://secure.flickr.com/",
    "storage"
  ],

  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "img/icon-19.png",
      "38": "img/icon-38.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Helios",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "content_scripts":[
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "css": ["css/main.css"],
      "js": [
        "js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.js",
        "js/vendor/handlebars-1.0.0-rc.4.js",
        "js/vendor/ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js",
        "js/vendor/d3.v3.js",
        "js/vendor/socket.io.min.js",
        "js/templates.js",
        "js/main.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],

  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "img/**",
    "fonts/**"
  ]
}
```

**Edit: Chrome version**

```
Google Chrome   29.0.1547.65 (Official Build 220622) 
OS  Mac OS X 
Blink   537.36 (@156661)
JavaScript  V8 3.19.18.19
Flash   11.8.800.170
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.65 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Your code should work as is. Can you add the contents of your manifest file?

Comment: I've added the manifest. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

From onMessage documentation.

> This function becomes invalid when the event listener returns, unless
>   you return true from the event listener to indicate you wish to send a
>   response asynchronously (this will keep the message channel open to
>   the other end until sendResponse is called).

So your code should look like

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log(sender.tab ? "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url : "from the extension");
  if (request.greeting == "hello") {
    sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
    return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: Yep i missed that, thanks. However, even after returning true i'm getting the exact same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: Please clarify, does this error message appear in background page console? Or in webpage console?

Comment: I have strong feeling that this is permission problem. You permission set to ...flickr..., but content "matches" set to wildcards. This is wird question, but do you test against https://secure.flickr.com/?

Comment: In the webpage console. Essentially, the initial message (from the content script) fails to send.

Comment: This actually means that background page did not assign onMessage listener at time of the call. Check you background page console, maybe some syntax error in the page script?

Comment: The error: Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".

Comment: background.html cannot include any scripts if you use manifest v2. You need to move yu code to external js and use script directives in background.html. Or easier way is to rename your background.html to background.js, remove any tags here and leave scripts only then put `  "background": {    "scripts": [ "background.js" ] }` into manifest instead of "page" value

Comment: Gotcha, i'll give that a shot.

Comment: @MihaiTomescu once you fix the inline script issue, note that you don't need to return `true` from the listener, as you are sending the response synchronously.